# Why does Rod Flanders have black hair in the episode "Lisa's First Word" (9F08)?

Tags: continuity, the-simpsons

In *The Simpsons* season four episode [Lisa's First Word](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Lisa%27s_First_Word) Rod is displayed as black-haired in one scene, but otherwise appears with his typical brown hair. I would have expected that the coloring errors are no longer present at this point in the show's production.

[image: screenshot]

*screenshot from the season 4 NTSC DVD*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not as exciting as it sounds. There are a ton of Simpsons characters that have incorrectly black hair, especially in the dark.

For example, from The Springfield Connection (S6E23) has Chief Wiggum with black hair when he should have blue hair identical to Marge.

[image: Screenshot]

It's even called out as a persistent issue in IMDB:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096697/goofs?item=gf0850439

> Chief Wiggum's proper hair color is blue. A common animation error is for it to be black in certain scenes (this generally happens in night scenes, or other scenes in dark places.)

Comment: It's also mentioned in at least one place in the DVD commentary (I don't recall which episode) by Matt Groening that the animation studio used for *The Simpsons* intermittently had issues with those sorts of details, which were uncorrected due to the expense of re-animating entire scenes in time for airing. He gives the specific example of the Loch Ness Monster episode, in which Nessie is purple rather than the intended green.